# iOS Thrift SSL Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssl, thrift

I have been using Thrift for data connections to server in my iOS app.  I would now like to secure it using SSL but it appears the libraries only have a Java solution for TSSLTransportFactory.

Does anybody have a solution for this for iOS?

Ted

Comment: I'm probably overlooking the obvious, but what programming language/environment are you using? Xcode? iOS is an operating system ...

Comment: I forgot: There is of course some more SSL support than just for Java.

Comment: I am using objective-c running on an iOS platform with Xcode as the IDE.  I am using the 0.9.1 version of the Apache Thrift libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two JIRA tickets [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2204) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2141), both with a patch attached which is not so old and should do it. We would appreciate your feedback wether or not you were able to use it successfully, both here at SO and in JIRA.

Comment: I am hoping this is well in the public domain now, but is there a sample implementation that you could point me towards? Particularly 2 components -- a) ssl file required, b) code to connect to a secure thrift server from objc/swift.

Comment: @arpwal: Unfortunately not, sorry. Maybe someone else can.